# Find $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\sin(\pi\sqrt[3]{n^3+1})$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, taylor-expansion

Find $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\sin(\pi\sqrt[3]{n^3+1})$. I am trying to find it using **Taylor series.**

What I did so far is: $\sqrt[3]{z+1}=1+O(z)$ (I really can't tell when I should be done developing it, and what is valid or not.) I get that $(\pi\sqrt[3]{n^3+1})=1+O(n^3)$. What do I do with that $O(n^3)$? (I know what I is but still.). Therefore (?) $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\sin(\pi\sqrt[3]{n^3+1})=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\sin(\pi (1+O(n^3))=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\sin\pi=0$??

I would appreciate your help, explanations, verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sqrt[3]{z+1}=1+O(z)$ holds for $z\to0$, but $n\to\infty$. You should use
$$
\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}=n\sqrt[3]{1+n^{-3}}=n(1+O(n^{-3}))=n+O(n^{-2}),
$$
$$
\pi\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}=n\pi+O(n^{-2}),
$$
And the formula for the $\sin$ of a sum.

Comment: I got that $\pi\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}=\pi n+\pi O(n^{-2})$. Is it equivalent to $\pi n$ immediately finishing the process?

Comment: In my opinion, it is better to apply the formula for the sinus of a sum. One of the terms will have $\sin(n\pi)$ and the other $\sin(O(n^{-2}))$.

Answer (score 2):

Your error term looks too big (you are probably doing your expansion around zero instead of infinity). Try to show that
$$
(1+n^3)^{1/3}=n+O(1/n^2),\quad\text{as}\quad n\to+\infty
$$
for example by making the Maclaurin expansion
$$
(1+t)^{1/3}=1+O(t),\quad\text{as}\quad t\to 0,
$$
(with $t=1/n^3$).

Comment: I have never done an expansion around infinity... How is it done?